# How do you make a balanced tree (let's say AVL tree) with a Hash Table for looking up a node?

Tags: java

This is a solution for some question in exam question. So I am supposed to make an AVL tree with an accompanying hash table for fast look up of a node in the tree. How am I supposed to do this? To be more specific, how do you make a pointer from a hash table to a node in the tree?

I prefer Java implementation since I am familiar with Java.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: wait are you currently taking the exam?

Comment: Tomorrow. I don't cheat. :) It was a past year question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Balancing is mostly a red herring here. When balancing you only move around nodes so you don't need to update the hash table. You only need to update the hash table when inserting and removing nodes from the tree.

Just insert the node in the hash table. Java uses references for objects so the hash table will always point to the node.

Comment: Would then updating the children and parent of a node update the corresponding node in the hash table?

Comment: Yes! You will save a reference to *the same object* in the hash table.